# Python unique merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 Dataframes:

**df1**

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| key_1 | 1100 |
| key_2 | 1100 |
| key_3 | 1100 |

**df2**

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key_2 | 1110 | xxv | cad |
| key_3 | 1110 | xxw | sder |
| key_4 | 1110 | xxt | dse |
| key_5 | 1110 | xxe | sdf |
| key_6 | 1110 | xxz | csd |

**My goal is to bring only the values in df1, if founds the same value of Column1 in df2**

My expected result would be this:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| key_2 | 1100 |
| key_3 | 1100 |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
out = df1[df1.Column1.isin(df2.Column1)]
```

Prints:

```
>>> out
  Column1  Column2
1   key_2     1100
2   key_3     1100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
df1.merge(df2['Column1'], on = 'Column1')
```

but I doubt this is what you are looking for. You really don't need a merge here. All you wanted to do is retain some rows in `df1`. But your question title suggests `merge`.